# Is there any library in angular to make such component?

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng, bootstrap-5

I have to make this design with functionality in angular. Searched for the library but didn't find one. Currently using bootstrap and primeng so if these provide any options please let me know.
Thanks much.[image]

[image]

Comment: Check https://ng.ant.design/components/calendar/en . It's similar to the one in your first image

Comment: You could check this library as well https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar?activeTab=readme

Comment: You could also use PrimeNG: http://primefaces.org/primeng/fullcalendar